# Powershell remove Em Dash in Filename Not Recognising Em Dash

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7

I'm unable to zip a large number of files as some filenames contain the Em dash character. I've been trying to use examples of PowerShell script to replace Em dash (0x2014) by En dash (0x2013), as described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dcfc8ea7-fbf7-4d33-8d8f-7596b7ac85ce/how-to-user-powershell-replace-to-remove-the-dreaded-em-dash-from-a-file-name?forum=ITCG) but it doesn't appear to be working for me in my Windows 7 environment. i.e. The PowerShell script doesn't appear to recognise that the Em dash character exists in the filename.

e.g. All the **–**'s in the following filename...

XXXXX **–** DMP **–** [version] **–** Partially Executed  [Date of latest signature]

...are not converted to En dashes.

...but just retains the '**–**'.

I've provided the script below, and am using PowerShell version 5.1.
Any help appreciated

```
function Replace-Text
{param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$text,
$em = ([char]0x2014),
$replacementlist = "$em,-,-,-,',,%,,$,,@,,#,,&,,’,"
)
Invoke-Expression ('$text' + -join $(
foreach($e in $replacementlist.Split(',')) { 
'.Replace("{0}","{1}")' -f $e, $(
[void]$foreach.MoveNext()
$foreach.Current) 
} 
)
)
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Rename-Item -NewName {(Replace-Text$_.Name).trim()}
```

Comment: The dashes in the filename you've posted are en-dash, check with `+[char]'–'` and see it is `8211` (the value of 0x2013). Your search for em-dash doesn't find them. That makes your question a bit unanswerable.

Comment: As an aside, it would be a simpler replacement to use regex, e.g. `$em = ([char]0x2014); $en = ([char]0x2013); $dashRegex = "$em|$en"; $symbolRegex = "['%@#&’$]"; Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $dashRegex, '-' -replace $symbolRegex, '' } -whatif`

Answer (score 2):

As TessellatingHeckler already pointed out, it's an `en` dash and not an `em` dash.

I'd suggest using the `-replace` regex operator with the `\p{Pd}` unicode class (Pd = "**P**unctuation, **d**ashes"), which will match both dash types as well as regular hyphens. You're replacement list can also be simplified drastically:

```
$Replacements = @{
    "[\p{Pd}]"                        = "-"
    "[$([regex]::Escape("'%$@#&’"))]" = ""
}
foreach($ReplacePattern in $Replacements.Keys){
    $text = $text -replace $ReplacePattern,$Replacements[$ReplacePattern]
}
return $text
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, I still have a problem with a long dash not being recognized by Powershell. Example filename with both long and short dashes,

11XXXXX – - DMP.txt

When I try and cut and paste these two types of dash into powershell command window (or even a Notepad session), they're both converted into short dashes. So, I don't have a way of replacing the long dashes and hence, cannot zip my folder structure. Does this help?

Comment: Renaming the file doesn't require any copy-pasting - `Get-ChildItem *DMP.txt |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\p{Pd}','-'}`

Comment: I think I have a fundamental problem with long vs short dash on my PC. The point I'm trying to make is that I am unable to test any solution as copying examples of long dash into a PowerShell (or Notepad) environment results in the long-dash character being reduced to a short automatically. E.g. I cannot copy the character '–' (long dash) into my PS script (or Notepad session) as it automatically becomes a '-' (short dash). My concern is that my PS script is never seeing the char '–' (long dash) in the filename, but interpreting it as a '-' (short dash).

Comment: I've been using the ISE debugger on filenames such as this... "11XXXXX – DMP – [version] - something.txt" and it never attempts to replace the long dash because it can't see it from the script in the first place. Either I've completely misunderstood how the solutions work or I have a local problem where the long dash character is being interpreted as a short dash and consequently, never fixing the filename. I may not have explained the problem very well but I do (I think) I understand the solutions your all providing. Is there anything else I can try to test my local environment? Cheers...

Comment: For example, If I copy the string "start – middle - end.txt" (i.e. One long and one short dash) into my PS command line or Notepad session, it becomes (without me doing anything but pasting) string "start - middle - end.txt" (i.e. Two short dashes). However, if I paste the string from Notepad back into this comment window, then the long dash reappears in "start – middle - end.txt". This is really weird but guess it's down to the long dash as not being a recognized ASCII char when presented or "read" by my PS scripts.

Comment: ...and my last example! With filename "11XXXXX – - DMP.txt" (as visible from Windows Explorer), when my PS script opens the file in the debug session, and I hover over variable $_.Name, the filename appears as "11XXXXX - - DMP.txt" before any processing is done to check for long or short dashes. The script suggested by Mathias never seems to see the long dash and leaves the filename (from Windows Explorer perspective) with a long dash.